# Trouble with catching values from a multidimensional array and display it in the text field where it was originally entered when form was submitted

Tags: php, html

I need help on how to retain the entered values in the text fields where user entered the value after submit. I'm having difficulty trying to figure out how to retain the values, because when I click on the submit button, the page refreshes and then values gone, and I have to retype them again.

Below is my form:

```
 <?php $count_name = count($x); ?>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th colspan="<?php echo $count_name; ?>"><strong>MR</strong></th>
     <th colspan="<?php echo $count_name; ?>"><strong>MS</strong></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php $_college = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM college");
        if(mysql_num_rows($_college)) {
        $i=0;
        while($row_college=mysql_fetch_array($_college)) { ?>
   <tr>
    <?php for($j=0;$j<$count_name;$j++) { ?> 
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="mr<?php echo $j; ?>[]" value=""/>
     <td>
     <?php } for($k=0;$k<$count_name;$k++) { ?> 
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="ms<?php echo $k; ?>[]" value=""/>
     <td>
     <?php } ?>
   </tr> 
 <?php } $i++;} ?>
 </tbody>
 <table>
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $count_name; ?>" name="totrows"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
```

Here's my code if button submit is click

```
<?php

if(isse($_POST['submit'])) {
$y = $_POST['totrows'];
$count_totcriteria = $y;
for($ab=0;$ab<$count_totcriteria;$ab++) {   
    $mr = 'mr_'.$ab;
    $ms = 'ms_'.$ab;

    $mr_score = $_POST[$mr];
    $ms_score = $_POST[$mr];

    foreach($mr_score as $key1 => $val1) {
        if(is_numeric($val1) && !empty($val1)) {
            $mr_val[] = $val1;
        } else {
                $msg = 'All fields are required and must be a valid score';
            }
    }

    foreach($ms_score as $key2 => $val2) {
        if(is_numeric($val2) && !empty($val2)) {
            $ms_str[] = $val2;
            } else {
                $msg = 'All fields are required and must be a valid score';
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

I know I have to put some code in the 'value=""' in order to display back the entered values when form is submitted but I am not sure what code to use. Not sure how to catch each array values.

Comment: What are `$x` and `$y`?

Comment: $x or $y are random numbers but they are always equal. e.g. if $x = 4, so does $y. So basically, the number of text fields will depend on what is $x. So when form is submitted, i get also the $y value which is equal to $x; this helps me check how many input fields are displayed in the form.

Comment: And why are you using mrN[] instead of mr[N] (and the same with ms) (where N is a number) or is that just a typo?  If not a typo, what are you doing with the array that makes it need to be an array?

Comment: i have modified my code above and the jsfiddle form here http://jsfiddle.net/L5knanna/1/.

Comment: Imagine a beauty pageant, you have mr and ms category and you have criterias for mr and ms category. You have two columns, mr and ms respectively. Under each of this column you have another columns, criteria columns for mr and ms. http://jsfiddle.net/L5knanna/1/

Comment: I used mrN[] because columns under MR are unique

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
<input type="text" name="mr<?php echo $j; ?>[]" value=""/>
```

you are looking for something like this (assuming $i is your new outer loop)

```
<input type="text" name="mr_<?= $j ?>[<?= $i ?>]" value="<?= @$_POST['mr_'.$j][$i] ?>"/>
```

and the same change for the `ms` line.

Does that work?

Comment: no this doesn't work, because each column under mr and ms must be validated. Imagine a beauty pageant, you have mr and ms category and you have criterias for mr and ms category. You have two columns, mr and ms respectively. Under each of this column you have another columns, criteria columns for mr and ms. http://jsfiddle.net/L5knanna/1/

Comment: You need to change where your `$i` is incremented: `   </tr> 
 <?php  $i++;}} ?>
 </tbody>
`. With that change I was successful in getting it to maintain the values - the code (as above) works...